# XPath of immediate child text vs all descendant text?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to retrieve up a category hierarchy from the following markup:

```
<ul class="categories">
    <li>My top level category
        <ul>
            <li>my second level category</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the name of the top level category using the following xpath:

```
//ul[@class='categories']/li/text()
```

But that obviously returns all of the text of that li including the second level categories.

How do I retrieve on the top level category using an xpath. You can assume that categories will only be two levels deep (Top level and second level categories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But that obviously returns all of the text of that li including the second level categories.

Actually, no, `//ul[@class='categories']/li/text()` will only return the ***immediate children text nodes*** of the matching `//ul[@class='categories']/li` elements.  In this case: `My top level category`.

Had you specified either of the following XPaths, you'd have also selected `my second level category`:

- `//ul[@class='categories']/li//text()`
- `string(//ul[@class='categories']/li)`